# Compilation issue, simple GLSL shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

Having recently acquainted myself with GLSL, I wrote this simple shader that is supposed to create an outline around the polygon that is being drawn in a 2D environment. However, I seem unable to get it past compilation as it baffles me with the following errors:

> Failed to compile fragment shader: 0(2) : error C0000: syntax error,
>   unexpected identifier, expecting '{' at token "tex"  0(3) : syntax
>   error, unexpected ')', expecting '::' at token ")"

And here is the shader in question:

```
uniform vec2 stepSize;
uniform sampler2d tex;
vec4 borderEffect(vec4 col, vec2 texture Post, sampler2d texture) {
   float outlineIntensity = 4*texture2d(texture, texturePos).a 
   - texture2d(texture, texturePos + vec2(stepSize.x, 0.0)).a 
   - texture2d(texture, texturePos + vec2(-stepSize.x, 0.0)).a 
   - texture2d(texture, texturePos + vec2(0.0, stepSize.y)).a 
   - texture2d(texture, texturePos + vec2(0.0, -stepSize.y)).a;

   return mix(texture2d(texture, texturePos), col, outlineIntensity);
} 

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = gl_Color*borderEffect(vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), gl_TexCoord[0].xy, tex):
}
```

So, my question is, what do these errors mean and how can I go about fixing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be uniform sampler2D, with a big 'D' in your 2nd line.

Comment: Wow, right, can't believe I missed that. Thanks anyway, mate :)